# Consulta MySQL com loop infinito

Tags: php, mysql

A minha página 'listagem.php' fica em loop infinito na hora de mostrar os valores.

Usei um `while` para mostrar todos os valores da banco de dados

O código em PHP usado na página **listagem.php**

```
<?php while($row = $resultado):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->ID; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->courseName; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row->date; ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $row->comment; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

A função com a **Query** está escrita assim:

```
function selectAll(){
    $this->connect();
    $resultSet = $this->pdo->query("SELECT comment.ID, courseName, name, date, comment FROM comment, course, teacher WHERE teacher.idCourse = course.ID AND comment.idTeacher = teacher.ID;");
    return $resultSet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer um `foreach` ?
foreach ($resultado as $row)

Comment: Ainda não, vou tentar aqui e ver se consigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar o foreach:

```
<?php foreach($resultado as $row): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $row->ID; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row->courseName; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row->name; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row->date; ?></td>
    <td><?= $row->comment; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro: "Warning: : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: como você montou a estrutura do foreach ? teria como vc copiar o seu código do foreach e colar aqui

Comment: O problema parece estar no retorno da função selectAll, onde a mesma parece não enviar um argumento aceito pelo foreach.

Comment: O argumento que o `foreach` espera é um array

Comment: Resolvido, mudei o retorno do selectAll para `return $resultSet->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Answer (score 1):

O motivo é simples, o `$row` nunca mudará o seu estado para `false`, nem `0` e nem `null`, consequentemente o seu loop ficará infinito.

Você provavelmente já viu algo desse tipo:

```
while( row = pdo->query("SELECT * FROM tabela") ){
}
```

O `query` irá retornar `false` quando não houver mais linhas, acho eu. Um comportamento similar é feito pelo `mysqli_fetch` (que explicitamente diz na documentação que retornará `NULL` quando "No more rows/data exists or data truncation occurred").

---

Mas... Esse não é o seu caso. Já que, quando você faz:

```
return $resultSet->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Você já retornando o resultado, ele será `false` ou ele já será o objeto, mas ele alternará entre objeto/false num momento posterior.

Se o resultado da `query` tiver um resultado, tiver ao menos uma linha, então você vai retornar um objeto e portanto sempre que fizer:

```
<?php while($row = $resultado):?>
```

Será o mesmo que fazer:

```
<?php while($row = (object)[""]):?>
```

Tanto o `$resultado` quanto o `(object)[""]` nunca serão `false`, neste caso, então seu loop será infinito.

Comment: Apesar de não apresentar a solução, foi MUITO útil para que eu pudesse entender o motivo do loop e agregar um pouco de conhecimento. Obrigado!!!